# embed python and pyc files in VxWorks 653 project

Tags: python, vxworks, micropython

We would like to create an embedded python application (interpreter together with a few custom python scripts in pyc format). The application would run on a VxWorks 653 platform (no file system, no Ethernet connection, etc.). I.e. it would be a completely stand-alone in RAM (and Flash memory) project. Yes, we can load RAM, Flash) over a connection, but in operation, it would be stand-alone except for our custom radio link.

Any pointers on how this can be done?

We don't need support from additional libraries and modules. Some of the standard library, but none of the OS specific stuff (files, os, tcp, etc.) will be used. (we do want the binary struct module).

It might be nice to be able to load strings of python scripts from memory and compile and run, but that is not crucial.

Comment: I see you've had some answers on the MicroPython forum at http://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=2660 . If any of that was helpful, you could summarise it here as an answer to your own question?

Comment: Nothing very useful so far for this particular part of the problem, i.e. how to do the import xxx when there is no file system. Says it can be done, and cites a system that did it. But still lacking exactly how.